# How to acquire DNSSEC root trust anchor from IANA?

Tags: digital-signature, dns, trust, dnssec

I want to establish trust in a DNSSEC record. I found, that it can be done

```
$ dig +sigchase +trusted-key=./root.key @8.8.8.8 eesti.ee
```

root.key could be obtained with

```
$ dig . DNSKEY @8.8.8.8 | grep -Ev '^($|;)' > root.keys
```

however, this would be insecure and suspectible to mitm attacks.

I believe that IANA publishes the root key on https://www.iana.org/dnssec/files (where it is signed with HTTPS, PGP, etc.), but it is in XML format and I failed to use it with dig.

**How** to convert it from XML to same format as root.keys **?**

Comment: Additional alternatives http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/148737/obtaining-the-public-dnssec-root-key

Answer (score 2):

You can download the Root Zone file on the [IANA website (HTTPS).](https://www.internic.net/domain/root.zone) This file contains the root keys you need. You can use `grep` to get the DNSKEY.

```
$ curl -s https://www.internic.net/domain/root.zone | grep "^\.\s\+[0-9]\+\s\+IN\s\+DNSKEY" > root.keys

$ dig +sigchase +trusted-key=./root.keys @8.8.8.8 eesti.ee
```