# Obtaining the public DNSSEC root key

Tags: dns, key-exchange, dnssec

Is the public DNSKEY of the DNS root zone that I have to trust when validating a DNSSEC key chain usually bundled with an OS? If so where is it located under Ubuntu 15.04, Linux?

What is otherwise the method to obtain it, that is considered "safe"?

I am using `dig +nocomments +nostats +nocmd +noquestion -t dnskey . > trusted-key.key` at the moment but I'd be interested in what the theoretically preferred solution of obtaining it would be.

Comment: I know it changes occasionally but OS vendors could distribute the new one as part of an update...

Comment: Overlaps http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/111454/how-to-acquire-dnssec-root-trust-anchor-from-iana

Answer (score 3):

`apt-get install dns-root-data` works on Ubuntu, at least in 16.04 and up. It also works on recent Debian.

Comment: Thank you. I just found https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7958 which answers my remaining questions I guess.

Answer (score 1):

This resource should be useful too: [IANA DNSSEC files](https://www.iana.org/dnssec/files). Note that there is a root key change planned for 2017.

A safe way is to use HTTPS to retrieve it **and** to check the server certificate.